# Zoom in ggplot after creating / reviewing

Tags: r, ggplot2, zooming

I'm making plots in batch mode.  While reviewing the graphs, it would be useful to zoom in on serval areas of interest.  Is there a way to zoom / rescale axis after the plot is made, and then restore it back to original axis range?

Answer, after incorporating feedback and comments....

```
set.seed(5)
gplist<-list()
for (i in seq(1,29)) {
  mod_evt = paste("plot",i)
  df <- data.frame(x=runif(10), y=runif(10))
  gp <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line() + geom_point() +
    labs(title = mod_evt, x="X", y="Y") 
  print(gp)
  gplist[[i]] <- gp
}
```

I'd like to zoom in on that dip near x=0.52 in plot 27

```
print(gplist[[27]] +  coord_cartesian(xlim= c(.5,.6)))
```

This reproduces the plot with x axis zoomed in between .5 and .6.

Comment: If you save the ggplot objects (and not just the plots), yes. You can reload them from an R data file and change any of the `scale_` parameters.

Comment: ok, I'll do that...  Thanks.

Comment: 1. Better form is to do `gplist[[i]] <- gp` instead of `gplist <- c(gplist, gp)`.

Comment: 2. Related, use `[[` for accessing single list elements (`[` gives you a list back`). Thus your last line should be `gplist[[27]] + ...`. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1169456/903061) for details.

Comment: ok, works after making above changes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, using `coord_cartesian` (or the appropriate `coord_xxxx`)

```
ex <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=drat, colour=factor(cyl))) + geom_point()

ex
```

[image]

```
# plot with "zoomed region"
ex + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(10,25),ylim= c(3,5))
```

[image]

```
# the original still exists
ex
```

[image]

If you have a list of plots

```
 plot_list <- list(ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=drat, colour=factor(cyl))) + geom_point(),
                   ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=drat, colour=factor(am))) + geom_point())
 zoomed <- lapply(plot_list, function(p) p + coord_cartesian(xlim= c(15,30)))


 # or for a single plot
 plot_list[[1]] + coord_cartesian(xlim= c(15,30))
```

Comment: I have the plots generated in a loop.  What type of variable can I use to store the plots by index, a vector?

Comment: store the plots in a list.

Comment: I did this...
gplist=list()
for (i in seq(1,29) {
  ... make plot
  print(gp)
  gplist <- c(gplist,gp)

Comment: I updated the question to include your solution, but I get an error, see above....

Comment: @user, your error comes from indexing the list using `[` not `[[`. `[` returns a list (as you can return one or more elements), `[[` can only return one element, and will return the element, not the list containing the element

Comment: I changed the access to [[]], but still get the same error.

Comment: Also had to change gplist <- c(gplist,gp) to gplist[[i]] = gp.  Thanks for your patience.